# Hide img if it equals a certain height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

I'm building a small portfolio with tumblr as my CMS and I need to have thumbnails on the index page. Without hardcoding this, the best way to make this happen seems to be to embed the thumbnail in the body post so the image is pulled through then hiding it on the post page by altering the css to `display:none' by matching it's unique height compared to other images.

It seems great in theory but currently isn't working. What have I missed? The parent div class is `.text`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hide = $('.text img').data-orig-height();
    if (hide === 167) {
        $('.text img').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $('.text img').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
</script>
```

Image html

```
<figure class="tmblr-full" data-orig-height="167" data-orig-width="310">
    <img src="http://40.media.tumblr.com/d190030c491be51fd47dd1f4291ae9c3/tumblr_inline_nxblnf7rF61tfshob_400.jpg" data-orig-height="167" data-orig-width="310" width="310" height="167" data-meow="true">
</figure>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [attribute-value selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('.text img[data-orig-height="167"]').hide();
```

This will select all the images inside the `.text` element having `data-orig-height` attribute value as `167`.

```
$('.text img[data-orig-height!="167"]').show(); // Show the images whose attribute value is not 167
```

---

In the OP code,

```
$('.text img').data-orig-height();
```

is not valid function. This'll throw `data-orig-height` is not a function error.

To get data-* attribute value, use [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2).

Comment: Thanks, hadn't considered that. Very concise answer.

Comment: Would you also want to add, $('.text img[data-orig-height!="167"]').show()? 

Seems like this may hide images permanently, but never show them.

Comment: @Spencer I assumed all the images will be shown by default and using `hide` can be hidden. But _if_ OP want to toggle images on some event, that'll not work. Thanks for suggestion, added.

Answer (score 3):

Three problems here:

1 - jQuery does not have a data-orig-height function. You can use the data function.

2 - === comparison will not result in type coercion, so "167" !== 167.

3 - Calling data will only return the first element's data. You want to handle each element individually, which warrants a for-loop.

Try the following:

```
$('.text img').each(function (k, img) {
    var $img = $(img);
    if($img.data('origHeight') == 167) {
        $img.hide();
    } else {
        $img.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: **Note:** This will not work _if_ there are multiple images, you'll need to iterate over them using `each`.

Comment: And, `if ... else` can be avoided by using `toggle()` as `$('.text img').toggle(hide !== 167);`

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my answer to handle multiple elements. I am not sure that toggle is the right function as that could result in elements being permanently hidden.

Answer (score 0):

This :

```
$('.text img').data-orig-height();
```

Should be :

```
$('.text img').data('origHeight');
```

Comment: **Note:** This will not work _if_ there are multiple images, you'll need to iterate over them using `each`.